# Reading a specific cell from excel file in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have written a program  in Matlab for designing evaporator. In this program i have to take latent heat of different fluids at different temperatures. I have latent heat values at different temperatures in an excel sheet. How can i get latent heat of fluid at specific temperature and assign it to certain variable in matlab.

Answer (score 1):

With xlsread you can read excel files and load values in to a variable. 
It goes like this: [variable,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename,sheetnumber,'C:C') 
With the sheet range you can specify the range of data that is put into the variable.